# I need help in an inventory project

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, timestamp

I have a sheet where only the product code will be entered if it is input or output
What I want is that when someone enters the column of the article code in another, the date on which that data was entered automatically appears
I tried using the NOW command, and it adds the information as I want but then it is modified as I use it then I use something that stays the static date and is variable when you enter something new
I await your response and thanks for your help

Comment: Just a suggestion...you might want to provide the code sample or screenshots...after all, a picture is worth of 1000 words.  :)

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on? (free of sensitive information)

Answer (score 0):

you need script for this task:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { 
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 3 ) { 
  var nextCell = r.offset(0, 7);
  var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
  "GMT+8", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  nextCell.setValue(newDate);
}
if( r.getColumn() == 4 ) { 
  var nextCell = r.offset(0, 6);
  var newDate1 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
  "GMT+8", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  nextCell.setValue(newDate1);
}}}
```

- `"Sheet1"` = sheet name
- `r.getColumn() == 3` = column C / 3rd column
- `r.offset(0, 7)` = offset timestamp 7 columns to the right on the same row eg column H
- `"GMT+8"` = timezone
- `"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"` = date and time format

Answer (score 0):

Change the SheetName, the column number and the column offset to fit you needs.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='SheetName' && e.range.columnStart==4) {
    e.range.offset(0,3).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
  }
}
```